# Complexity of Turing self-reducibility of Clique problem?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reductions

I'm interested in the complexity of self reducibility of a variant clique problem. Namely, the NP-complete problem HALF Clique: given a graph on $N$ nodes, Is there a clique of size $N/2$ in the graph?

How hard is it to reduce an instance of HALF CLIQUE of input size $2N$ to an instance of size $N$ using Turing reduction? Is there a Cook reduction? I'm looking for references for upper bounds and lower bounds on the complexity of Turing reductions of this type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not a reference, but an NP-complete problem cannot have a polynomial-time self-reduction which halves the input size unless NP has a *n*<sup>O(log *n*)</sup>-time algorithm, even if we allow Turing reductions.

Suppose there is a *p*(*n*)-time Turing reduction from an NP-complete problem *L* to itself such that given an input of length *n*, the reduction only makes queries to strings of length at most *n*/2.  Then you can convert this reduction to a standalone deterministic algorithm for *L* by using recursion.  By writing down a recurrence relation for the running time of this deterministic algorithm, it is not hard to see that it runs in time *n*<sup>O(log *n*)</sup>.